# How do i find the corresponding index for these two vectors?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In clojure I'm trying to get my order-finder vector to find the index of a name in the names list:

```
(def customer-names ["Adam" "Beth" "Chloe" "Daniel" "Nathan" "Olivia"])
```

To then use that index to find the corresponding pizza orders in this vector

```
(def pizzas ["P" "M" "P" "C" "P" "P" "S" "C" "M" "M" "S" "C"])
```

Where by each person in the list will have 2 pizzas per order (in the same order as the customer list)

```
(defn order-finder [customer-names][pizzas]
  customer-names(.indexOf v "Adam")
    (.indexOf (pizzas = (.indexOf (customer-names * 2)))))
```

As I'm new to this language i wonder if it is even possible to do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your actual requirement is to lookup the pizzas by customer name.  And getting `.indexOf` is just an interim step - which you would skip to make things simpler.

```clj
(def customer-names ["Adam" "Beth" "Chloe" "Daniel" "Nathan" "Olivia"])
(def pizzas ["P" "M" "P" "C" "P" "P" "S" "C" "M" "M" "S" "C"])

;; each customer has 2 pizzas - so the pizzas array can be re-arranged like:
;;
(partition 2 pizzas)
;; => (("P" "M") ("P" "C") ("P" "P") ("S" "C") ("M" "M") ("S" "C"))

;; now the order finder is just a `Cojure` map with keys as 
;; customer names, values as the pizzas ordered
;;
(def order-finder
  (zipmap customer-names (partition 2 pizzas)))
;; => {"Adam" ("P" "M"), "Beth" ("P" "C"), "Chloe" ("P" "P"), "Daniel" ("S" "C"), "Nathan" ("M" "M"), "Olivia" ("S" "C")}

;; Now to find pizzas by customer name, just look it up from the order-finder map:
;; 
(order-finder "Adam")
;; => ("P" "M")
```

Comment: Yeah this works great thanks. do you know if there's any way to move back to the start and add additional items in the same order once it reaches the end of the names vector?

Comment: You mean to add a new customer name with another set of pizzas?   You can do `(assoc order-finder "Rimon" '("P" "M"))` - which will return an updated `order-finder`.